# What time are the "Wee Hours"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, time, measure-expressions

What period of time is considered **Wee Hours**?
From 12:00am to 05:00am?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Wee' is Scottish English for 'small', so "the wee hours of the morning" could be understood to be the 'small' (or low) numbers on the clock.

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wee-hours) defines it as "*the early hours of the morning, between twelve o'clock at night and the time when the sun rises*", but sunrise varies greatly in many places. For example, where I live in the UK, the sun rose this morning (which just happens to be the day before winter solstice) at 8:28 am - *long* after many people have risen for work or school. At the Summer solstice, the sunrise is approximately 4:43 am.

As a native British English speaker myself, I can tell you that most people consider it to mean any time from after midnight but before the time you would reasonably expect to wake. Your suggestion of 5 am seems about right, as some people rise as early as 6 am for normal daily routines like work or school. The point is that there is no precise, prescribed time.

Comment: You often hear 'the wee small hours', and not just in the Scottish part of the United Kingdom. Longman says midnight to 4 AM, which I think is a bit over-precise.

Comment: tbh, it's any time you look at the clock in the night & swear. There is no precision required if you really don't need to be up yet. ;)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Agreed, it's just the word 'wee' that I made a point of saying is Scottish, not the phrase.

Comment: @Astralbee - ah, sure, it crops up every wee while in Northern Ireland, so it does.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey that's Scottish influence, though. If it was Gaelic in origin then they'd say it in the republic of Ireland, too.

Comment: I would like to thank you @Astralbee for the answer. Can you guys please upvote my question? It's a fair question, I don't know why someone downvoted it.

Comment: @PedroMuniz - just guessing here, but I think that complaining on here about downvotes or asking for upvotes is a pretty good way to get downvotes. It kind of puts the idea into people's heads. A better guess is 'lack of research effort', considering that 'wee' and 'small hours' are defined in plenty of dictionaries or even just by Googling "wee small hours meaning".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey hmmm, got it. Do you think I should delete that comment?

Comment: @PedroMuniz - comments are temporary. All comments are liable to be deleted at any time by the moderators, and not because of any judgements, just to tidy up the site.